# Looping over a JSON file with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to loop through this JSON string (which is in a separate json file called language.json) but nothing's working

```
{
    "language": [
    {
        "name": "English Languages",
        "values": ["English 1", "English 2", "English 3", "English 4"]
    },
    {
        "name": "French Languages",
        "values": ["French 1", "French 2", "French 3", "French 4"]
    },
    {
        "name": "Spanish Languages",
        "values": ["Spanish 1", "Spanish 2", "Spanish 3", "Spanish 4"]
    }
    ]}
```

jQuery

```
$.getJSON("script/countries.json", function (data) {  
     $.each(data.language, function (i, v) {
     var category = data[i];
     console.log(category.name)
     $.each(category.values, function (i, v){
         console.log(category.values[i])
     });
 });
```

Can anybody help me here. I want to print Lanugage Name and then it's list of values.

OUTPUT:

```
English Language:
English1
English2..
French Language
French1
French2
```

and so on 
Thanks!

Comment: whether your ajax callback is getting called.. and what is the value logged for `data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `callback` is getting called and the `data` is having the desired value.

`data[i]` will return undefined because you are iterating through `data.language` so you need to use either `var category = data.language[i]` or [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) will pass the current value as the second param to the callback. So you can

```
//this will iterate through the data.language list and for each item in the array the callback method will be called. 
//The callback method will receive the index of the current item and the item as its 2 parameters
$.each(data.language, function (i, category) {
    //here category is the current item in the data.language array so it has the name and values properties
    console.log(category.name)
    //the same logic follows here, we are iterating through the values array and since it is an array of string calues the second param lang will be the language
    $.each(category.values, function (i, lang) {
        console.log(lang)
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain your code in detail. It works but I am not able to understand fully.

Comment: @user1089173 in your code you had used `var category = data[i];`, so it will turn to `var category = data[0];` but if you look at your data, the `data` object does not have a key called `0`. Actually you needed the value at index `0` of `data.language` that is the reason for the failure of your code

Comment: totally get what was wrong in my code. I want an explanation of your code line by line. Also when the json is in the same file with your code, it works fine. I put the json in a separate file and run it, it gives me an unexpected token error. Why?

Comment: fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lpjs8pxy/1/ works fine when json is declared internally. But when in a separate file, it works but with Unexpected Token error

Comment: can you check your browser network tab to see what is the value returned?

Comment: no values returned at all. I checked this thread 10080551/weird-json-parsing-behavior-in-js-unexpected-token and it seems it has an explanation but no solution

Comment: Ok in chrome it returns 304

Comment: @user1089173 it is because the file is cached... change `"script/countries.json"` to `"script/countries.json?_" + new Date().getTime()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61819/discussion-between-user1089173-and-arun-p-johny).

Comment: Hell! I renamed the file and the error went away :) Thanks for your help. Can you explain your code step by step

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
var category = data[i];
```

should be

```
var category = data.language[i];
```

Comment: Please put some explantion to answer you posted that will help others to get it quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code:

```
$.getJSON("script/countries.json", function (data) {  
     $.each(data.language, function (i, v) {
         var category = v;//updated
         console.log(category.name)
         $.each(category.values, function (i, name){
             console.log(name);//updated
         });
     });
});//missing added
```